# writing and running make files

Tags: makefile

I'm on a windows machine, I downloaded a program with 1 cpp, 1 header and a makefile. now the same program has several cpp and header files located in a source and header folders (including the original cpp). how can i edit the make file to correspond to this change, and how can I run it (I have never run a make file before).

This was the original makefile...

```
 Code.exe: code.cpp
    cl /nologo $** 

clean: dummy
    -@del code.exe
    -@del code.obj

dummy:
```

Comment: Have you tried running the original makefile? And do you know how to compile the new source files by hand (without a makefile)?

Comment: no i dont know hoe to run a makefile, i did it in java once but i lost my notes. i added the source and header to visual studio so i didnt need the make file but i think its one of those fundamental principles a programmer should at least know how to use, and create basic ones.

Comment: A makefile basically automates tasks you would otherwise perform on the command line. Do you know how to use `cl`?

Comment: i know roughly what a make file is, just not how to make one or run one from the command line.i just need to know how to edit the already made make file to take into account the directories the files are in, and how to run it from the command line. my command line experience is very limited too.

Comment: You can't learn makefiles without understanding how to use the command line, and since I'm not familiar with `cl`, I'm not sure how to modify your makefile.

Comment: since it looks like you are building on windows are you sure youre using make and not nmake? nmake is a little different than gnu make so its important to know